# Post processing the videos into one

Tags: node.js, sockets, video-streaming, webrtc

I am developing a video interview app using webrtc. The video streams of the interviewer and interviewee(and also the screen sharing recordings if any) are stored separately as individual videos.

What I need now is to post process the videos automatically into one final file after the interview has been completed. The final video should contain the interviewee's and interviewer's video feed side by side as the interview happens(and also include the screen shared video as background if any).

I have few queries on this:

- Is there any ways we can achieve this automatically or can we process the videos live as the interview happens?
- The videos are saved every 10 secs as the interview happens. Can we stream the chunked videos without merging them?

This [article](http://blog.adeel.io/2017/07/13/streaming-html5-video-through-node-js/) explains the video streaming of a single file. Is there ways to do the same if the the files are saved as chunks. This [article](https://bloggeek.me/recording-webrtc-sessions/)
explains my exact scenario but does not provide the coded solution.